# Changing the blue color of phone number on mobile version

Tags: html, css, ios

On the mobile version of my website (IOS) the phonenumber is shown in blue which I want to remove the Blue or change it for an other color.

I would prefer to do it with: inline Styling

this is my code

```
<section class="xs-header-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="header-top-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="icon icon-map-marker2"></i> Chicago/li>
                        <li><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> frfee.meo@hotmail.com</li>
                        <li><i class="icon icon-phone3"></i> (434) 434-45343</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .col end -->
```

I tried to do add this `style="color:yellow"`

```
<li><i class="icon icon-phone3", style="color:yellow"></i> (434) 434-45343</li>
```

But It change the ICON color, which is not what I want. I want to change the phone number color to white.

Comment: "*But It change the ICON color, which is not what I want. I want to change the phone number color to white.*" Then why not apply the inline style to the parent `<li>` instead? Can you explain why that doesn't meet your requirement?

Comment: It does the same thing on IOS when I apply the color in the parent <li>. The number is still in blue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the phone number to its own css element (i.e. span)

```
<li><i class="icon icon-phone3"></i><span style="color:yellow">(434) 434-45343</span></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, it change the color on the desktop version but on mobile version the number number is still shown in blue

Comment: You can try adding the !important property which will override any previous styling like: style="color:white !important"

Comment: I just tried it and it still shown in blue

Comment: Last thing I can think of is adding text-decoration:none, as well. So : style="color:white !important; text-decoration:none;"

Answer (score -1):

Add this to head tag:

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

Comment: While this does prevent browser styling of detected phone numbers, it also removes the "automagic" hyperlink functionality, which the OP has not indicated whether or not they are actually seeking.

Comment: I guess that will remove the click on call options